# 「かしこまる」と言う自動詞について / About the verb "kashikomaru"

Tags: verbs, set-phrases

皆さんこんにちは、
日本語で質問がお聞きしてみたいのですが、言葉や文法を間違えたらお許しください。

では、「かしこまりました」とは誰かに命令や注文を頼まれた場合などの返事とすることもよくありますが、「かしこまる」と言う自動詞がこの表現以外で使われる場合はありますか？

"kashikomarimashita" is usually used as a response to somebody's order or request, but are there places where the verb "kashikomaru" is used other than in this expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  かしこまる ([Daijirin](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%93%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_kasikomaru_-010), [Daijisen](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/40482/m0u/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%93%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B/)) has three usages which are commonly seen.  The examples below are from Daijisen:

1. To behave humbly to show the respect to the other party.  Ex. かしこまってあいさつする。
2. To sit up straight in the [正座](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiza) style.  Ex. かしこまっていないで、ひざをお崩しなさい。
3. (As you wrote in the question,) かしこまりました is a humble expression used when the speaker accepts a request from an honorified person.